# Get users login/logout status from Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory

We have an intranet application where all users are on Azure AD. Is it possible to see when a certain user logs in/out, or at least see current logged in/out-status (so we can show which users are currently online/offline inside our application.)

Our users might not open our application at all one day, but we basically want to know if they are siting by their desk at a given moment (so we cant track them by if they are logged in to our app or not).

Ideal case would be subscribe to an event (using .net/c#), else a powershell script that runs regularly is ok too. Any suggestions welcome

Comment: You could see the Sign-Ins report in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

Comment: I need to read this information programmatically (through an api, library or similar), preferably in real-time

Comment: ...but thanks though. Youre comment has got me in the right direction. Im looking at this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-access-api-with-certificates and this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/howto-configure-prerequisites-for-reporting-api now

Comment: You could also keep track of the users' last login time in a database. Remove that if they log out, and consider them logged out if time since logged in > session lifetime. Now if you have sliding session duration then you'd have to refresh that login time..

Comment: The thing that I perhaps didn't mention(updated post now) is that our users might not log in to our application at all that day. Basically we want to know if they are sitting by their desk or not.